# Java/Scala - hmacSHA256 signature different every time

Tags: java, scala, digital-signature, hmac

I'm getting this strange behaviour where sha256 signiture is coming out different for the same input and key every time. Not sure why. Here is the code and some of the printlns.

```
def apply(algorithm: String, data: String, key: String): Array[Byte] = {

  val _key = Option(key).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing key for JWT encryption via " + algorithm))
  val mac: Mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm)
  val secretKey: SecretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(_key.getBytes, algorithm)
  mac.init(secretKey)
  val res = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes)

  println(s"$algorithm $data $key $res $secretKey")
  res
}
```

Here is the logging from the testsuite using this code:

```
HmacSHA256 eyJIZXkiOiJmb28ifQ== secretkey [B@4959742d javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77d7a8
HmacSHA256 eyJIZXkiOiJmb28ifQ== secretkey [B@6a790e37 javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77d7a8
HmacSHA256 eyJIZXkiOiJmb28ifQ== secretkey [B@2347f330 javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77d7a8
HmacSHA256 eyJIZXkiOiJmb28ifQ== secretkey [B@5298db1f javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77d7a8
HmacSHA256 eyJIZXkiOiJmb28ifQ== secretkey [B@5cb80eb0 javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fa77d7a8
```

Why are the signatures all different??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not looking at the signature, you're looking at the default toString() method call on an Array of bytes.  If you inspect the actual bytes, they should match.

Comment: And as a side note: this `[B@5cb80eb0` is decrypted as byte array (`[B` part), with the `5cb80eb0` memory address inside JVM (the rest). So in practice, you have a number of different byte arrays in your heap, which may contain the very same bytes, of course.

Comment: I realized what I was looking at on my way to work - thanks guys.

Comment: Gah I skipped a piece of the requirements - that the hmac was supposed to be base 64 encoded. Working on a JWT lib... https://github.com/jasongoodwin/authentikat-jwt

Comment: As a side note to your side note @om-nom-nom, it is [B to indicate byte array and the 5cb80eb0 is actually the hex representation of the hashCode() method which may or may not be the memory address in the heap depending on the implementation.  Not that it matters to this question in any way...      http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

Comment: This getOrElse with a throw inside... is really ant functional programming. You should use that Option all over the code with map.